# Rename multiple pictures stored in array

Tags: php

This is how I store my array of pictures to folder and MySQL rows.

```
$pictures       = array_filter($_FILES['pictures']['name']);
$total_pictures = count($_FILES['pictures']['name']);

for($i = 0; $i < $total_pictures; $i++)
{
    $tmpname = $_FILES['pictures']['tmp_name'][$i];
    if($tmpname != "")
    {
        $filepath = $target . $_FILES['pictures']['name'][$i];
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $filepath))
        {
            $picture_data  = Array(
                "product_id" => "$product_id",
                "picture" => "$pictures[$i]"
            );
            $insertpicture = $db->insert('products_pictures', $picture_data);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to rename my pictures before its uploaded and the name stored to database, but every time I try, I get errors related to string and array conflicts.

Comment: 1. Please indent your code so we can read it.. 2. Please post what you tried so we can help you figure it out. As it stands you're just asking us to write the solution from scratch.

Comment: You do not need to put variables inside of double quotes. For example, `"product_id" => "$product_id",` could just be `"product_id" => $product_id,`

Comment: Yes im asking to write a solution from scratch becouse its just one or two lines of a code to add time() prefix or something to my pictures. I tryed many things to do that, but all of them ends in conflict between array and string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this snippet to generate a unique ID everytime and append it to your filename.

```php
substr(md5(microtime(true).mt_Rand()),1,6);
```

It generates a random string value and strips it to 5 characters for smaller filenames.  It uses microtime to get current time, generates a random number based on that and then hashes it with md5.

```php
for($i = 0; $i < $total_pictures; $i++)
{
    $tmpname = $_FILES['pictures']['tmp_name'][$i];
    if($tmpname != "")
    {
        $uniqHash = substr(md5(microtime(true).mt_Rand()),1,6); // Generate the 5 char hash
        $filepath = $target . $_FILES['pictures']['name'][$i];
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $filepath.$uniqHash)) // Append the hash to $tmpname to make it unique everytime
        {
            $picture_data  = Array(
                "product_id" => "$product_id",
                "picture" => "$pictures[$i]"
            );
            $insertpicture = $db->insert('products_pictures', $picture_data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tryed many snippets like this and everytime i get errors,  can you suggest  a correct way of using this snipped in my situation?

Comment: is `'tmp_name'` already coming in the array of files?

Comment: added code to the answer, read the comments in there and let me knwo

Comment: thank you! after some editing i made it work as intended. very helpfull answer.

Comment: There is an easier way to generate a random-looking name: `bin2hex(random_bytes(3))`.